# markedDates object in React Native Calendar not marking all Dates

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I am working with the React Native Calendar object, and I am having a little difficulty. Essentially, I take two arrays of objects, each object with a date property, and I combine all of these dates into one big array, which I then iterate through to complete the `markedDates` object in the format that React Native Calendar Expects. Observe...

what `markedDates` is on the documentation

```
markedDates={{
    '2012-05-16': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
    '2012-05-17': {marked: true},
    '2012-05-18': {marked: true, dotColor: 'red', activeOpacity: 0},
    '2012-05-19': {disabled: true, disableTouchEvent: true}
  }}
```

My `markedDates` object

```
markedDates={{
  {
    "2022-09-12": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#E892F8", "marked": true},
    "2022-09-14": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#E892F8", "marked": true}, 
    "2022-11-07": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#ED1286", "marked": true}, 
    "2022-8-31": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#ED1286", "marked": true}, 
    "2022-9-12": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#ED1286", "marked": true}, 
    "2022-9-16": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#ED1286", "marked": true}}
}}
```

The first two dates, `2022-09-21` and `2022-09-14` render on the calendar properly, but the other dates are not marked at all. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: The whole page? It uses a few recoil states too

Comment: like i mean, what all youre trying for this particular issue, only the working part of it

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@nlanese/trusting-milkshake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill tell you the problem :

[image]

Its working here, ive changed your markedDates object to below and this works,

```
markedDates={{
  {
    "2022-09-12": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#E892F8", "marked": true},
    "2022-09-14": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#E892F8", "marked": true}, 
    "2022-11-07": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#ED1286", "marked": true}, 
    "2022-08-31": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#ED1286", "marked": true}, 
    "2022-09-12": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#ED1286", "marked": true}, 
    "2022-09-16": {"color": "rbga(255, 255, 255, .30)", "dotColor": "#ED1286", "marked": true}}
}}
```

In keys youve missed to add 0 to month `2022-08-31`(this is correct),  youve just written `2022-8-31`(which is wrong)

https://snack.expo.dev/9yB_jxrV0 do check out the snack,

Hope it helps :)